# PHP included class not updating if modified

Tags: php, oop, class, autoload

I create a simple class from a different file and include it
to a page that used to create an object of that class.
Everything works fine, the problems occurs is when I update
the class, I need to manually access the class from my browser
then the page that I create the object will get the latest modified class
or it will receive Error.

below is the page code I use to create an object of the class

```
<?php

function __autoload($class_name) {
    require '/classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}

$rain = new myClass;
echo $rain->TestMethod(12345,123451);
?>
```

If I update my class, and without accessing it manually from my browser I will receive this error from my Apache2.

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/classes/myClass.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your folder structure? Looks like your autoload is looking into a wrong directory.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the name of the file and the location where the class is defined ?

Comment: Try to use 'classes/'.$class_name . '.php';

Comment: Thanks @NorbertOrzechowicz , it solve my problems, I thought I need to start it with the slash .. I remove the slash and it work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are using a PHP op cache, or any Apache PHP cache or something that makes your php files not been readead from disk when you change them.

I usually have many problems with shared servers because these modules.

(i see the `/` is the root folder. It's a common mistake if your classes are not in the root folder of your webserver.)

Comment: It's in the root folder. It the problems with the location of my file.
I place it inside the folder of classes in my root document and I include it with the location of "/classes/myClass.php". I thought the location need to start with the slash. I remove the slash and it's working now.